# Jest/Enzyme ReactJS Testing Form Control Option

Tags: reactjs, testing, bootstrap-4, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to write unit tests for a form I have in a component.
I have this at the moment which works fine for any 'text input' parts of the form however for dropdown selects it doesn't work...

```
it('should set the gender on change event', () => {
    wrapper.find('#gender').simulate('change', {
        target: {
            value: 'female',
        },
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('#gender').props().value).toEqual(
        'female',
    );
});
```

It just says that it expected 'Female' but got nothing.

This is what I am trying to test -

```
<Form.Group as={Row} controlId="gender">
    <Form.Label column sm="2"> Gender </Form.Label>
        <Col sm="10">
            <Form.Control defaultValue="" as="select" value={gender} required onChange={event => setGender(event.currentTarget.value)}>
                <option value="" disabled>Choose...</option>
                {data.gender.map(opt => <option key={opt}>{opt}</option>)}
            </Form.Control>
        </Col>
</Form.Group>
```

I have been googling and trying a number of things but can't get it to work! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Any suggestion for this question?